Не получается создать WASD управление на Godot
Я много раз пробовал создать управление WASD на Godot, но у меня ничего не получилось. Я действовал по официальной документации. Вот список действий:

Код:
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed = 10

func _physics_process(delta):
    $".".look_at(get_global_mouse_position())
    
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("KeyInpUP"):
        velocity.y -= speed
    if Input.is_action_pressed("KeyInpDOWN"):
        velocity.y += speed


Во-первых, is_action_just_pressed и is_action_pressed ведут себя по-разному. Во-вторых, вы скорость-то изменили, а применить её забыли, например через move_and_slide() какой-нибудь или напрямую отредактировав position

Спасибо большое!
